# SQL Trigger not firing while inserting from SAS

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sas

```
USE [dbname]
   GO
   SET NOCOUNT ON
   GO
   ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[my_trigger]  
   ON [dbo].[Table_1]  
   AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE   
   AS  
   EXEC  msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
          @recipients = 'xx@companyid.com', 
          @profile_name = 'PQM',
          @subject = 'Data Inserted', 
          @body = 'Hi Data has been inserted';
   GO
```

This code executes and the mail is triggered when i insert from the SQL Server management studio or using a VBA code. But when i insert from SAS server end the mail is not triggered neither does the triggered fired.

SAS coding

```
proc sql noprint;
connect to odbc as sql1(datasrc= PQMDB USER= 'XXXX' PASSWORD = 'XXXX');
create table tr as select * 
from connection to sql1
  (insert into dbname.dbo.Table_1 values('abc1');
disconnect from sql1;
quit;
```

This code executes fine when i disable the trigger at the SQL end.

Comment: Are you sure you're connecting to the same database? And another thing - is the row inserted in the second case with the trigger enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Had to chnage at SAS end and used "Execute() by <*connectionname*>; and that helped and the sql is firing the triggers now finely

Comment: I am surprised the other syntax even ran. What did the WORK.TR table in SAS look like?